# Allow access only for robot.txt via http, others at https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, robots.txt

I want to redirect all my traffic on https, only the robot.txt should be accessible via http.

Is it possible to create an exception for the robot.txt file?

My .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R=301]
```

Comment: Note that it must be named `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? Should the rules in the `robots.txt` work for your HTTPS site?

Comment: If a client access the Page without https i redirect him automaticly, but google need the robot.txt without https, there was a access error in google admin tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```

Make sure this is very first rule in your root .htaccess.